# How can I separate API response into 2 arrays?

Tags: php, api

I'm making a project using an API and want to separate the API response data into 2 arrays (true and false). What do I need to do?

The API endpoint returns this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "itemId": "d930dba-8e19b63-a6d5d94-6978fe3",
        "lastUpdate": 1556668801,
        "store": {
            "isFeatured": true,
            "isRefundable": true,
            "cost": "1500"
        },
        "item": {
            "name": "Star-Lord Outfit",
            "description": "Do something good, something bad, a bit of both!",
            "type": "outfit",
            "rarity": "marvel",
            "images": {
                "icon": "https:\/\/fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com\/outfit\/a6bac035952059b94ba5e665f6f5a0f0.png",
                "featured": "https:\/\/fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com\/featured\/d930dba-8e19b63-a6d5d94-6978fe3.png",
                "background": "https:\/\/fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com\/image\/d930dba-8e19b63-a6d5d94-6978fe3.png",
                "information": "https:\/\/fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com\/image\/d930dba-8e19b63-a6d5d94-6978fe3\/item.png"
            },
            "obtained_type": "vbucks",
            "ratings": {
                "avgStars": 4.06,
                "totalPoints": 1691,
                "numberVotes": 416
         }
    }
},
```

I've tried so many things, this is one:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($image_data['data'][$i]['store']['isFeatured']['true']); $i ++) { }
?>
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by saying "want to ungroup two results from the data": you want to get 2 separate arrays or you want to sort you data array on `isFeatured`?

Comment: I want to get 2 separated arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function. here is a sample code which will do what you need:

```
function getFeaturedImages($item){
    return $item['store']['isFeatured'];
}

function getNonFeaturedImages($item){
    return !$item['store']['isFeatured'];
}

$featuredImageDataArray = array_filter($image_data['data'], 'getFeaturedImages');
$nonFeaturedImageDataArray = array_filter($image_data['data'], 'getNonFeaturedImages');

$featuredImageArray = ['data'=>[]];
$nonFeaturedImageArray = ['data'=>[]];

foreach($featuredImageDataArray as $value)
    $featuredImageArray['data'][] = $value;

foreach($nonFeaturedImageDataArray as $value)
    $nonFeaturedImageArray['data'][] = $value;
```

At the end you `$featuredImageArray` will hold data for `isFeatured = TRUE` and `$nonFeaturedImageArray` which will hold data for `isFeatured = FALSE`

Comment: So much days without finding a solution for this. Any suggestions on how to improve?

Comment: @Benj1148 there are always many improvements on any code, but you know a lot depends on what input and output params, so I can't say what can be improved based on such a little portion of code :)

Comment: `$nonFeaturedImageArray` is now giving me the `$featuredImageArray` and two images more (from nonfeatured)

Comment: @Benj1148 please provide full code and JSON in order to be able to help you

Comment: Code after functions: [after functions](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wZbbeG)                                   JSON: [json](https://pastebin.com/PKdcpb3B)

Comment: @Benj1148 sorry but your code is not full, and according to provided JSON you have total 10 items from which only 4 are featured and the code which I have provided is returning all this data. maybe you are doing some data manipulations which is not represented in the code?